# vlookup generates #N/A and correct data as well

Tags: excel-2007, vlookup

While using vlookup within the same Row, some of the cells generate correct results but some of them generate `#N/A`. All the source data is correct in the sheet from where I'm taking it.
The generated data is sorted serially but the source data is not serial, is the problem related to "auto fill"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey everyone I got my problem solved huuuuuh
the problem was auto fill that increased the table array range due to that vlookup generated #N/A.
When I drag the first cell the range started increasing and my array range was ,D1:D255,
and after D93 as there was no information stored in that cell as the last cell was D90